# Parent div to display alongside children divs

Tags: html, css

my current output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahXK9.png). I am trying to figure out how to get the "General Tax Knowledge (compFamilyHierarchyName class) to run vertically next to the blue boxes and looke like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2T03.png).

The closest I've gotten is adding display:flex to the compFamilyHierarchyName, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVnJ8.png) - "General Tax Knowledge" is in the right place, but the blue boxes are now on the same line and I can't figure out how to get them to go back to being on top of each other.

I appreciate any help or pointers. Thank you!

```css
.outerCompFamilyName{
 width:60px;
 background: #009CDE;
 position: relative;
 border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.innerCompFamilyName{
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 36%;
 left: -30%;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.whiteCDF {
 background: white;
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
 border-right: 1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<div class="compFamilyHierarchyName">General Tax Knowledge
    <div style ="display:flex" class="FunctionalExpertise  Credits_Incentives_Methods column"> 
     
     <div class="outerCompFamilyName">
     <div class="innerCompFamilyName" >Accounting Methods and Periods</div>
     </div>
     <div id="BuildingProfessionalNetworksTest16" style="width: 95%; background: slategrey;">
      <div class="whiteCDF">Approaches and participates in all internal/external interactions with professionalism</div><div class="whiteCDF">Actively develops an internal/external network and relationships to grow one’s career, enhance business advisor status with clients, build the practice and serve clients; knows the right people in market/industry</div>
 </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
    
    <div style ="display:flex" class="FunctionalExpertise  Credits_Incentives_Methods column"> 
     <div class="outerCompFamilyName">
     <div class="innerCompFamilyName" >Planning and Consulting</div>
     </div>
     <div id="BuildingProfessionalNetworksTest17" style="width: 95%; background: slategrey;">
      <div class="whiteCDF">Approaches and participates in all internal/external interactions with professionalism</div><div class="whiteCDF">Actively develops an internal/external network and relationships to grow one’s career, enhance business advisor status with clients, build the practice and serve clients; knows the right people in market/industry</div>
 </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

For context - [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfQAJ.png) is the look we're trying to recreate for the site. It's the general organization of previously advertised materials/internal communications, so we're doing our best to recreate it for continuity.

Comment: I think image one is the preffered style to begin with. Not sure why you would want it next to the blue boxes. This is because the the blue boxes are headers for that table and so probably belong there, however the general tax knowledge is a header for the table. I think it should stay where it is.

Comment: I've added an image at the bottom of my post explaining the overall look we're going for. Basically, there are already headers, so the div I'm moving isn't the header itself, more like a grouping for columns. We're trying to recreate the look of how this information is currently organized/advertised internally for continuity.

Comment: Why don't you put "General Tax Knowledge" in an inner element?

Comment: Put Gen Tax in a div and place it inside the container of the other one. Then if you need to float, float left or something to move it over

Comment: I'm trying moving the General Tax Knowledge div around, but don't think I'm really following what you both are saying. (Sorry!) When I put Gen Tax inside the outermost div I can get it to float to the left of one of the blue boxes, but not both. Could you show me what you mean?